# How to delete a cookie in Mojolicious

Tags: mojolicious

I am trying to delete a cookie.

How do i delete a cookie in mojolicious or how do i set response cookie expiry date to past date.

Plz! help
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$self->session(expires => 1)`. Also try the [fantastic mojocasts](http://mojocast.com)

Comment: This deletes a session not cookie.

Comment: link to `fantastic mojocasts` is broken

Comment: And the link was probably advertising anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete cookie by setting an expiration date in the past. For example, you can write following code in controller: `$self->cookie($cookie_name => '', {expires => 1})`.